# How to add an attribute to an <img> tag having a specific text values in the textfield.JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have an `<img>` tag attached to each `<text>` tag as shown below:

```
<div>
  <text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 1</text>
  <img src="abc.png" class="nv-hover-icon" height="15" width="22"/>
</div>
<div>
 <text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 2</text>
 <img src="abc.png" class="nv-hover-icon" height="15" width="22"/>
</div>
<div>
  <text text-anchor="start" class="text">Text 3</text>
  <img src="abc.png" class="nv-hover-icon" height="15" width="22"/>
</div>
```

how can i add an attribute to an image whose text == 'Text2'.

```
if($("text.text").text() == 'Text 2'){
   //add an attr 'id' to the img tag
  //pseudo code: $("img").attr("id", "image-id");
}
```

any ideas on how to achieve this?? 
Thanks!!

Comment: `$("text.text").text()` is this working?

Comment: I think its `img` tag.

Comment: Never heard `<image>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
$('.text').each(function(){
    if($(this).html().indexOf('2')>0)
    {
       $(this).next().attr('id','img2');
    }
});
```

Please check below fiddle for the code.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6yodq8v/)

Or You can also do like this.

```
$('.text').each(function(){
   if($(this).html() == "Text 2")
   {
      $(this).next().attr('id','img2');
   }
});
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/u6yodq8v/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this : You can use `.filter()` to find desired text and then use `.next()` to locate image and add attribute

```
$("text.text").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().trim() == 'Text 2';
}).next().attr("id", "image-id");
```

**[API Doc for filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in combination with [**.next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

*Code*

```
$("text.text").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == 'Text 2'
}).next("image").attr("id", "image-id");
```

Additionally, It should be `img` tag instead of `image`